# `react.cloneElement` ignores className, how can I give something a className?

Tags: reactjs

Reading through the docs, it seems that the now deprecated `cloneWithProps` merged the `className`s, but `cloneElement` ignores the `className` that's passed in

https://jsfiddle.net/z12hc5er/1/

```
var Foo = function () {
    return <div className="shows-up">Hello World</div>;
};

var Bar = function () {
    return React.cloneElement(<Foo/>, {className: 'ignored'});
};

ReactDOM.render(
    <Bar/>,
    document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Is there any way to influence the className of a cloned element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`className` is an attribute of a particular element in `Foo`, what if you had multiple elements with classNames?

The second parameter is for passing props. Props are just a way of passing data to the component, react doesn't assume how you want to use them, so you'd have to explicitly tell it, e.g:

```
var Foo = function (props) {
    return <div className={props.className || 'shows-up'}>Hello World</div>;
};

var Bar = function () {
    return React.cloneElement(<Foo/>, {className: 'not-ignored'});
};

ReactDOM.render(
    <Bar/>,
    document.getElementById('container')
);
```

I guess they decided that doing something special with `style` and `className` (and ignoring `key` and `ref`) was too opinionated in `cloneWithProps`.

Edit: Looking here it looks like it was actually done of optimisation reasons: https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/03/10/react-v0.13.html